# Unexpected reserved word 'await' in in jest tesing

Tags: reactjs, async-await, jestjs

I am developing a react-native application. but it gives a error as given bellow image in the console. here I have attached both js file and test file.

---

**Error display in the terminal**

Test suite failed to run

```
SyntaxError: C:\Geethma\skyU_frontend\skyu-frontend\src\features\dashboard\components\jest-tests\ExpandedInstancDetails.test.js: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (10:8)

   8 |       }
   9 |     it("should go to after click",()=>{
> 10 |         await act(async () => {
     |         ^
  11 |             render(
  12 |               <Router history={mockHistory}>
  13 |                 <ExpandedInstancDetails />

  at instantiate (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parse-error/credentials.js:61:22)
  at toParseError (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parse-error.js:58:12)
  at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/tokenizer/index.js:1763:19)
  at Parser.checkReservedWord (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2718:12)
  at Parser.parseIdentifierName (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2653:12)
  at Parser.parseIdentifier (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2621:23)
  at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1256:27)
  at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:683:23)
  at Parser.parseUpdate (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:662:21)
  at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:631:23)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.712 s
Ran all test suites.

---

**ExpandedInstancDetails.js file**

```
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const ExpandedInstancDetails = () => {
      let history = useHistory();
    
      function handleClick() {
        history.push("/home");
      }
    
      return (
        <button data-testid="button" type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
          Go home
        </button>
      );
    }
export default ExpandedInstancDetails;
```

---

**ExpandedInstancDetails.test.js file**

```
import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';    
import ExpandedInstancDetails from "../ExpandedInstancDetails";

describe('HomeButton', () => {
  
  const mockHistory = {
    push: jest.fn(),
  }

  it('should go to home after click', () => {
    await act(async () => {
      render(
        <Router history={mockHistory}>
          <ExpandedInstancDetails/>
        </Router>
      )

      userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('button'))
    })

    
    expect(mockHistory.push).toBeCalledWith("/home")
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`await` needs to go along with `async`. Your unit test does not declare `async`, so that's why it's throwing an error.

For the fix, you should add `async` after `it` instead of inside of `act`

```
import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';    
import ExpandedInstancDetails from "../ExpandedInstancDetails";

describe('HomeButton', () => {
  
  const mockHistory = {
    push: jest.fn(),
  }
  
  //add `async` after `it`
  it('should go to home after click', async () => {
    await act(() => {
      render(
        <Router history={mockHistory}>
          <ExpandedInstancDetails/>
        </Router>
      )

      userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('button'))
    })

    
    expect(mockHistory.push).toBeCalledWith("/home")
  })
})
```